# RCNN draws rectangles inside of rectangles

Tags: conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I constructed quite simple RCNN (keras, sequential model) to identify cuneiform in engraves. It is supposed to draw about 11 rectangles in the picture below, where the cuneiform is (ground truth). The rectangles should not intersect. As a result I get around 25 rectangles that are inside each other. Would anyone more experienced share ideas about the root cause and steps I should take or try? I am posting the code that computes the result but the error may very well be in the IOU or training.

```
...
if e < 2000:
   x, y, w, h = result
   timage = imout[y:y+h,x:x+w]
   resized = cv2.resize( timage,                                  \
                         ( image_edge_lenght, image_edge_lenght ), \
                         interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA             \
                         )
   img = np.expand_dims( resized, axis = 0 )
   out = model_final.predict( img )
   #out= model_final.local( img )

   if out[0][0] > 0.70:
      cv2.rectangle( imout,     \
                     ( x, y ),   \
                     ( x+w, y+h ),\ 
                     ( 0, 255, 0 ),\
                     1,             \
                     cv2.LINE_AA     \
                     )
...
```

[image]
[Picture of current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPJak.png)

Comment: I don't think the code you show is responsible for the error. Where does `result` come from?